# Under what circumstances is it forbidden to move a 'k'li shemelachto leheter' (a utensil whose purpose is for a permitted use)?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, muktzeh

[Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 308:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.308.4?lang=bi):

> כלי שמלאכתו להיתר מותר לטלטלו אפי' אינו אלא לצורך הכלי שלא ישבר או יגנב **אבל שלא לצורך כלל אסור לטלטלו**: וכתבי הקדש ואוכלים מותר לטלטלם אפי' שלא לצורך כלל:‏
>
> A utensil whose purpose is for a permitted use [on *shabbat*] is permitted to be moved, even if only for the sake of the utensil itself, so that it not break or be stolen, **but for no purpose at all, it is forbidden to move it**. Holy writings and food may be moved, even for no purpose at all.

I'm having a little trouble thinking of a scenario where this rule applies. **How does one move something for no purpose at all?** Even if someone is playing or fidgeting with an object, would that not be considered moving it for the purpose of keeping his hands busy?

Please present (sourced) definitions / parameters of what is considered 'moving something for no purpose at all'.

Comment: I think the standard interpretation is that, at least according to the Shulchan Aruch, fidgeting is not a significant enough purpose to allow kli shemlachto l'heter. Follow-up questions: are fidget-spinners then muktza? What if fidgeting is one's oneg shabbos and/or medically recommended?

Comment: Thought sworn we had this question already, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Thought or sworn??

Comment: You are in good company having trouble thinking of that scenario! The _Aroch Hashulchan_ [says](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A9%D7%97#%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%9F_%D7%A9%D7%97_%D7%A1%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%A3_%D7%98%D7%95) it practically doesn't exist!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

{This is not "definitions / parameters of what is considered 'moving something for no purpose at all'" but just an example. I will happily remove it if you feel it is totally inadequate as an answer.}

[This site](http://etzion.gush.net/vbm/archive/yomyom/dafyomyomi/2013-02-04.php)  has a commentary on Shabbos 124 and gives an example of 'moving something for no purpose at all'  as follows:

> "למשל, יש שהורו להוציא מן הכיס או מן החגורה צרור מפתחות שאין כוונה
>   להשתמש בו בשבת. אמנם, מפתחות אינם מוקצה ואף אינם כלי שמלאכתו  לאיסור,
>   ואף על פי כן, הם אינם נחוצים לשבת  ולכן יש להימנע מטלטולם שלא (1)
>   לצורך! “

(note 1: The original has the word “ של" which I have changed to “  שלא")

> For example they are those who teach that one should remove from the
>   pocket or the belt a bunch of keys which one does not intend to use on
>   Shabbos. These keys are not muktza nor are they keilim whose use is
>   prohibited; even so they are not needed for Shabbos and therefore it
>   is right to refrain from moving them for no purpose.