# Is a Pasul Torah scroll considered a Muktzeh on Shabbat?

Tags: shabbat, sefer-torah, muktzeh

I know that there are different categories of Muktzeh. One category that is difficult for me to understand is the concept that if something has no use at all on Shabbat (or use for any purpose) it is considered a Muktzeh. I would think that a pasul Torah scroll, which is something that can't be used on Shabbat, at least, would be considered muktzah, no?

Further questions regarding handling pasul Torah, even if it may be considered muktzah:

- Can one move it if it is in front of a kosher Torah that one wishes to use, now?
- If while reading the Torah for the congregation, the reader discovers something that now makes the Torah pasul, can it be moved back to the ark? If not, how may it be handled?

Comment: Why would it be unusable on Shabbos? You might not be able to fulfil your obligation of Krias Hatorah with it, but it's still usable as a Torah (i.e. for learning).

Comment: @Salmononius2 Much of the laws of muktzah have to do with one's intention of its use prior to when Shabbat began. Generally, if one did not intend to use it on Shabbat - and a pasul Torah is generally not intended for use - it cannot be moved, usually. Hence, the 1st question. This reasoning does not apply to the Torah that became pasul.

Comment: You refer to a Torah scroll, right, not to Chumashim?

Answer (score 2):

Excellent Question!  The Orchos Shabbos 19:139 (cited [here](http://din.org.il/2018/05/13/%D7%94%D7%90%D7%9D-%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8-%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94-%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%9C-%D7%94%D7%95%D7%90-%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%A6%D7%94-%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%AA-%D7%97%D7%A1%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9F/)), explains that the Sefer Torah is considered Muktzah because of [Chisaron Kis](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12166/16354), but in terms of many particular cases where it is necessary, we consider it either not muktzah, or as a [Kli Shemelachto Leheter](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/95156/16354), see there for details of each particular case.